# formulae / algorithm to select centre cells in a grid?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, grid, formula

If I have a grid say consisting of 15 x 15 cells (but variable), what formulae or algorithm  would I use to randomly select 20 cells clustered around the centre cell?

I guess I would ideally like to be able to set the centre point, cluster radius, density etc...

any pointers would be really appreciated! cheers.

Comment: Hm ... you need to pick the right distribution, and assign a probability to each cell (they better add up to 1). Then, keep grabbing random numbers between 0 and 1, and pick the *right* cell. The right cell is where you end up when you start with cell at (0,0), then move to the next one if your rand num was greater than that prob, while also subtracting a prob of that cell. This is not the fastest approach, but for 15 x 15 will do just fine. The trick is picking the right distribution for the grid, which will favor center the most - it is up to you, because there are many options.

Comment: Take a look at cdf vs pdf of discrete distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_probability_distribution You do not need to jump into heavy math, just get an idea about difference between cdf and pdf for discrete distribution. That should explain why you would keep on moving from cell to cell untill you find the *right* one. How you order the cells is up to you. You could order them in a spiral-like fashion, and then apply some sort of triangular distribution. You could also separate grid into several squares or circles, and say that prob of being anywhere on that shape is the same.

Comment: For a grid that is 15x15 or so, you can concoct a quick and dirty distribution manually - just give more weight to the center. If you can have lots of different grids, then you better use a clever formula, but then again, it needs not be perfect. You just want to make sure to "normalize" relative probabilities at the end, so that everything adds up to exactly 1. For instance, the probability of being at square (x,y) can be proportional to 1/r where r is distance to the center. For the center itself, you want to assume some high enough probability instead of 1/0. After you get relative numbers

Comment: Thanks for the info - You've put me onto some good thoughts, however Ive just used the code from below and that seems to be adequate for my needs right now. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

monte carlo?

`<pseudocode>`

```
found=false
sigma2=3;             // variance
centrex=8; centrey=8; // centre point
while !found
  x=random(15)        //for a 15x15 grid of course!
  y=random(15)
  r2=(x-centrex)^2 + (y-centrey)^2   // squared distance to chosen point
  p=exp(-r2/sigma)                 // probability of accepting this point
  if(p>rand(1)) found=true;        // (calcluated as gaussian distribution)
end
```

`</pseudocode>`

You can choose your distribution using the formula on the `p=` line.
here the spread of the distribution can be controlled using the `sigma` value. For a flat distribution just use `p=r2<9` for a radius of 3 for example.

for a gaussian, the radius and density are essentially the same thing, as the integral of `p` over `x` and `y` has to add up to 1.

Comment: Great thanks - this seems to be exactly what I was after!

I just need to add a method for checking duplicate cells, and experiment with  different sized x and y scales - Will this work as expect with say 11 * 15 grid or does it need to remain square?

Comment: It will work with any sized grid, but as it stands the distribution of chosen cells will remain circular. To make it oval, change the scale in r2 i.e. `r2=((x-centrex)*15/11)^2 + (y-centrey)^2` to preserve the shape.

Comment: Oh and to prevent duplication you should keep track of previously chosen items with a boolean 15x15 array initialised with false. Then change the '`found`' line to: `if(p>rand(1) & !previouslyChosen[x,y]) { found=true; previouslyChosen[x,y]=true; }`

Answer (score 1):

Randomness within a circle is known paradoxical problem (see Bertrand's paradox). So you need to consider how to randomly distribute the points. Choosing a random distance ranging from 0 to the specified radius, and going in a random direction from the the circle's center (the grid's center) is probably not what you want, since you will have an uneven distribution across the area (more clustering towards the center). I would figure out the AREA of the circle (that is: the cells that are within the circle with the specified radius), maybe store them in a temp array, and choose n (e.g., 20) of them at random. I am not sure that was entirely helpful, but the main idea: DO consider what you mean by random.

Comment: thanks, some more to think about there! at the moment the answer above seems to solve the issue for me